# CSpinCtrl works in Windows11 in opposite direction

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

I use `CSpinCtrl`.
Until I have changed to Windows 11, upper arrow increase value in buddy EditBox and lower arrow decrease value.
When I changed to Windows 11, the direction turned.
I am able to solve it with my own subclassed control, of course. But - is not there any easier solution?

Comment: You should be able to just swap you minimum and maximum values? According to MS documentation **"Any time the minimum setting is greater than the maximum setting (for example, when the default settings are used), clicking the up arrow decreases the position value and clicking the down arrow increases it."**

Comment: I can't imagine that Windows 11 would ship a UI change *this* counter-intuitive. Can we see your code, ideally a [mcve]?

Comment: I can see three possible explanations: 1) you changed something and forgot about it; 2) your values depend on something that has changed with the OS; and 3) your code has, and always had, undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the [`CSpinCtrl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/using-cspinbuttonctrl?view=msvc-170) does this. I quote:

> By default, the range for the spin button has the maximum set to zero (0) and the minimum set to 100. Because the maximum value is less than the minimum value, *clicking the up arrow decreases the position and clicking the down arrow increases it*. Use `CSpinButtonCtrl::SetRange` to adjust these values.

Just set the values as stated and all should be fine.

Comment: When I look back on my own experience with CSpinCtrl, it has been this way since 20 years at a minimum.

Comment: @j6t I agree. There is no need for him to subclass controls. He should be able to use `SetRange` but he has not shown any code to replicate the issue.